# Flutter vertical ScrollSingleChildView not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following function

```dart
buildVideos() {
    var videos = super.getVideos();

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var video in videos) Container(child: Text(video["thumbnail"]))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The above code gives me the overflow error (yellow strip). But When I change the `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal`, it works fine. I have tried wrapping it in `Expanded` widget with no success.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: add a widget where you are calling this method because i think problem is not in this method.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: add more information related to this question.